# How to use Vim as the default text editor in Ubuntu but using Tilix as default terminal for it?

Tags: gnome, vim, text-editor

I am currently using Vim as the default text editor in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. However, Vim opens by default with Gnome Terminal, and I would like to know if it is possible that Vim would open directly with the Tilix terminal instead.

I tried editing the vim.desktop file in /usr/share/applications so it would open with Tilix. However, with this approach, when I try to open a text or any other file with Vim, it does not appear as a choice on the editors list.

Any help would be great!

Thanks in advance,
Iago

Comment: I don't have Tilix installed, but based on the documentation I'd expect that replacing `Exec=vim %F` by `Exec=tilix -e vim %F` (and possibly changing `Terminal=true` to `Terminal=false`) ought to work. FWIW I'd also recommend copying `/usr/share/applications/vim.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications/vim.desktop` and modifying that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I did exactly that (but didn't changed Terminal=true to Terminal=false). However, when I do this the application Vim, in the 'Open with' menu, disappears, and I only get access to a file opening Vim first. I will try your suggestions!

Comment: @steeldriver your suggestion worked! I forgot to add the %F on the whole command :) thanks very much!